# Which @3x pictures shall I select in iPhone X and iPhone 8 Plus

Tags: ios

I am doing a background image for iPhone.
On iPhone 8 plus, the resolution is 1242 x 2208 in pixel.
On iPhone X, the reslution is 1125 x 2436 in pixel.
Both of them require for @3x in iPhone App development.

My question : which reeslution shall I make for @3x ?

Comment: Use either, but set your image view's `contentMode` to `aspectFill`

Comment: I reckon the correct answer is: 1242 x 2436 px